# One to Many [Polymorphic] Association with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Here are some entities:

```
public class Zone : AbstractGuidKeyedEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneGroup : AbstractGuidKeyedEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}

public class Contract: AbstractGuidKeyedEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the rules:

1. A `Zone` can belong to a `ZoneGroup` or a `Contract`.
2. A `Zone` cannot belong to both a `ZoneGroup` and a `Contract`.

Here is what I want:

1. One join table that has a unique id on zone.

What I will settle for:

1. Something that works.

How do I fluently map this with Entity Framework 4.1?

Thank you for your brain power.

-- EDIT --

Here are the tables I would like.

```
            Zone          
--------------------------
| ZoneId     | Name       |
==========================
| lkj-lakjd  | Front      |
| asd-jkllk  | Rear       |
--------------------------

         ZoneGroup          
--------------------------
| ZoneId     | Name       |
==========================
| uio-asdfd  | Z71 Boat   |
--------------------------

          Contract
--------------------------
| ZoneId     | Name       |
==========================
| zxc-qwert  | Hugo Taylor|
--------------------------

         ZoneGroupContractZone
--------------------------------------
| ZoneId     | ZonableId  |  Type     |
======================================
| lkj-lakjd  | uio-asdfd  | ZoneGroup |
| asd-jkllk  | zxc-qwert  | Contract  |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show db tables you want to get. It's not clear from your description.Also be prepared to make compromises in your requirements.